# Syntax error in 'AS' in my count query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I used `select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))` in my count query. I think error might be in `select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))`. This is `Syntax` error.

**My Code:**

```
$data = DB::table('finaltrade')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"));
```

[image: here is result].

Comment: What is the error?  The `WHERE` clause looks complicated to me.  There could be a problem there.

Comment: I have edited my question, browser show me `Syntax` error. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: OK...but _what_ is the error message?

Comment: Let me  add your screen-shot if error.

Comment: I have added result @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I was hoping to see the MySQL error which is being thrown.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `count(*) as count`, per se...http://rextester.com/NOHY81407

Comment: Should I not expect result `{ "count":"1" }` ? @Strawberry

Comment: did you try adding `->get()` or `->first()` ?

Comment: actually I am really confused where should i add `->get()` or `->first()` in my above code. @MehravishTemkar

Comment: try adding it at the end of your code. Or at least share the error

Comment: When I add `->get();` at end of code, then it show me `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` @MehravishTemkar

Comment: I hope you know you are supposed to add it before the ending semi-colon

Comment: Why you are using this way? we have `eloquent` in Laravel that make everything easy for you @KinnariPrajapati

Comment: Actually I am new for laravel, I want to learn `eloquent` if i got help. @ArashHatami

Comment: Can you please try to add `->get()` or `->first()`?

Comment: If i add this both function at end of the code with semi-column or not, it give me error `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)` @MehravishTemkar

Comment: copy the code i posted and try it

Comment: thank you, your code id worked for me UP-VOTED by me@MehravishTemkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `get()` or `first()`

```
$data = DB::table('finaltrade')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"))
->get();
```

Or

```
$data = DB::table('finaltrade')
->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
->join('exchanges', 'finaltrade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
->where('finaltrade.user_id', $user_id)
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '>=', DB::raw('exchanges.start_time'))
->whereTime(DB::raw('IF(finaltrade.buy_datetime<finaltrade.sell_datetime, finaltrade.buy_datetime, finaltrade.sell_datetime) '), '<=', DB::raw("ADDTIME(exchanges.start_time, '1:00:00')"))
->first();
```

Comment: I got result... wow thank you. I have to find what was the my mistakes...

Comment: As much as I know you should use `first()` and not `get()` in this case. Accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: there is a check icon below the vote arrows, click on it, it will accept the answer

Comment: Oh really, I was aware of it how to accept the answered. Thank you so much @Mehravish Temkar